# Динамическое формирование label для textAreaRow

Tags: bootstrap, yii

Использую `yii bootstrap`. Не понимаю как в представлении изменить `label` для `textArea`.

```
 $form->textAreaRow($question,'statement',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64));
```

в `HTML` получается:

```
<label for="Questions_statement">Statement</label>
<input class="span5" maxlength="64" name="Questions[statement]"  id="Questions_statement" type="text" value="ворпос 1">
```

в модели есть `public function attributeLabels()`, но мне нужно формировать `label` динамически. Вопрос в том как это реализовать.

Comment: $form->textAreaRow($question,'statement',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64,'labelOptions'=>array('label'=>' my label !!!')));

Comment: Пригодилось. Спасибо.